# VBA найти ячейки с определённым значением и добавить их в листбокс

Tags: excel, vba

Есть пример, который делает следующее:

```html
Найти в диапозоне "A1:A50" все ячейки с текстом "asd" и поменять их все на "qwe"

With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A50")
  Set c = .Find("asd", LookIn:=xlValues)
  Do While Not c Is Nothing
    c.Value = "qwe"
    Set c = .FindNext(c)
  Loop
End With
```

Как его переделать, чтобы он искал на листе "ФИО" ячейки, содержащие "Иван", и добавлял их в ListBox1?

Comment: *listBox* где? На форме? На листе? Вы нашли какой-то "левый" код, но ни своих данных, ни *listBox* не показали

Answer (score 0):

Опираясь на скудную информацию в вопросе:

```
With Worksheets(1)
    For i = 1 To 50
        If InStr(" " & .Cells(i, 1).Value & " ", " Иван ") Then
            UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem .Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Проверка слова с пробелами, иначе ошибочно могут определиться значения с похожими данными (например - *Иванович*)

Вместо `InStr` можно искать другим оператором:

```
If " " & .Cells(i, 1).Value & " " Like "* Иван *" Then
```

если *ListBox* на *UserForm*, то обращаться нужно как к элементу формы:

```
UserForm1.ListBox1
```

Если  на листе, то -  как к объекту листа

```
.Shapes.Range(Array("ListBox1"))
```

Но при этом нужно сначала создать отдельный диапазон с отобраными именами.